# How to create a local empty JSON Model from OData metadata

Tags: sapui5

Is there a way to create a local empty JSON file (with all entities and properties filled in) from the metadata of the oData service? I need this for the create scenario, where I can bind the properties to the view controls. I tried the following code, but did not work. Will appreciate your suggestions.

```
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().getMetaModel().getODataEntitySet("EntitySetName");
```

Error:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getObject' of null
>
> at constructor.h.getODataEntityContainer (ODataMetaModel-dbg.js:692)
>   at constructor.h.getODataEntitySet (ODataMetaModel-dbg.js:731)
>   at eval (eval at _prepareCreatePage (ObjectPage.controller.js:74), <anonymous>:1:48)
>   at f._prepareCreatePage (ObjectPage.controller.js:74)
>   at f._onObjectPatternMatched (ObjectPage.controller.js:40)
>   at constructor.b.fireEvent (EventProvider-dbg.js:228)
>   at constructor.<anonymous>
> ```

Comment: I suggest you use `createEntry` and bind that.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what exactly you'd like to achieve by reading the metadata? Would you like to display some annotations (things like `sap:label="..."`)? What version of OData are we dealing with? _V2_ or _V4_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAP does very similar stuff in their sample pages: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.table.Table/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.OData2/code

Your first part is more or less correct, this is a function to store the meta model in a seperate JSONModel:

```
function () {
    const that = this;

    const oModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    const oMetaModel = oModel.getMetaModel();

    oMetaModel.loaded().then(function () {
        that.setModel(oMetaModel, "meta");
    });
}
```

The interesting part is how to access stuff:

```
const sBasePath = "/dataServices/schema/[${namespace}===\'NAME_OF_YOUR_ODATA_SRV\']/entityType/[${name}===\'NameOfYourEntity\']"
const oEntityInformation = oMetaModel.getProperty(sBasePath);

const aKeys = oMetaModel.getProperty(sBasePath + "/key/propertyRef");
const aAllProperties = oMetaModel.getProperty(sBasePath + "/property");
const oSingleProperty = oMetaModel.getProperty(sBasePath + "/property/[${name}===\'NameOfYourProperty\']");
```

You can even access the model in your XML view:

```
columns="{
    path: 'meta>/dataServices/schema/[${namespace}===\'NAME_OF_YOUR_ODATA_SRV\']/entityType/[${name}===\'NameOfYourEntity\']/property',
    factory: '.columnFactory'
}"
```

Note that `NameOfYourEntity` has to be the name of the single Entity, so there is no `Set` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, what you want exactly but this script will write the metadata in JSON format in a blob. The save dialog in browser appears after that.

```js
var oDataModel = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();

oDataModel.attachMetadataLoaded(null, function() {
  var oMetaData = oDataModel.getServiceMetadata(); //Read the metadata
  var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(oMetaData)], {
    type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"
  }); //Create a blob with metadata string in JSON format

  if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    return navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, "metadata.json"); //For IE
  } else {
    //For Chrome and FF we create a Link with a download attribute and trigger the click on it
    var sUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob); //Create the URL for the blob object
    var oLink = document.createElement("a"); //Create link element
    oLink.download = "metadata.json" //Set download attribute for link
    oLink.href = sUrl; //Set href attribute for link
    document.body.appendChild(oLink); //Append link to body
    oLink.click(); //Click on link
    oLink.remove(); //Remove link
  }
});
```